# How can i access activity menu items from fragment in Android?

Tags: android, menuitem

I have a class that  `extends ActionBarActivity` and make use of a `ViewPager` as well. I want my menu to be availble in all the fragments (3 tabs)and not only see the menu (that happends) but to actually respond to the logic per each menu item.

In activity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 ...
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In each fragment:

```
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);
    @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
        }

    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
             ...
            return false;
      }
```

In fragment nothing happends when I choose an option from the menu, and i don't understand why. I am doing something wrong, just don't spot it. Any ideas would be great. Thank you.

Comment: The ActionBar belongs to the activity, not the fragment. Why can't you handle it in the activity? Also, `ActionBarActivity` is now deprecated, I would switch to `AppCompatActivity` when you can.

Comment: Thank you. I postponed doing that out but I changed to extends AppCompatActivity. Menu items not reacting yet.

Comment: The menu items won't, because they're handled by the Activity, not by the Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment you must specify that there is a menu with setOptionsMenu(true)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```